# How would a platform or core code design look like in a microservices architecture?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design, microservices

In a monolithic architecture, you would have a core/platform code on top of which a bunch of services or business domains would be built. Some examples being, db abstraction, external service abstraction etc.

In case of micro services, would the platform code be written as a module, which would be imported as a dependent module in each of the micro services or, does this violate the construct of the architecture because of tight coupling between the module and the common (core/platform) code and thereby going back to the issues related multiple deployments, code bugs, vendor lock ins etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microservices in the current context they are being referred to today are intended to be stand alone, a service with no dependence on another service (Data stores as well, dedicated to the microservice).

It is a good idea even if not going the microservices route to divide your application into smaller modules/services/packages etc.. This will allow for more maintainable code.